# How to delete a .txt file after a certain time?

Tags: php, text-files

I have this .txt file that displays information but I want to delete itself after like 5 minutes or so.

Comment: What have u done so far? Please [read how to ask good question on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You could run a CRON every 6 minutes...

Comment: I haven't tried anything for now but basically I have these PHP files that get Ips and sends them to a txt file and I need that file to refresh itself every time theres a new ip in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering what you are doing, won't using memcached be a better option?
You just store your ips as key=value pairs in memcached, with an expiry of 5 minutes. Thus your data always expires every 5 minutes.
Also interaction with memcached is much easier than file-handling.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just need to know how to use memcached because I have never heard of it XD. Is it hard to configure it to get IPs?

Comment: Its a piece of cake. Also PHP has a memcached extension that you can use. http://memcached.org/ and http://php.net/memcache